# In the new Snowflake Worksheet UI, how do you see the query history?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the "Classic Console" worksheet, at the bottom right you could see the query history, which was great for jumping around results set, and comparing SQL performance times.

[image]

How is this type of thing done in the new UI, I feel I have clicked on all the UI elements, but cannot find a history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest to the classic console history would be Home-->Activity. At least you won't have to toggle between versions to look at query durations. Luckily, it opens on a separate tab and can be refreshed. TBH, the classic console has it better.

[image]

Comment: oh, I really like this. This was what I was looking for. The "open as a new window" works very well for that nature of the "how I was using it".

Answer (score 2):

you could click on the history at the top right hand corner , it will show the different version of SQL executed, may be this is what you want.

[image]

Comment: hmm, I noticed that was jumping through the history of the sheet, so wrote it off. It does allow seeing the results, and I strongly dislike the workflow of it. But answer my fundamental question you have. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks , it is little confusing and not like "Classic Console" or may be we are used to the look and feel of the old "Classic Console".

Answer (score 1):

From the top corner history you can mouseover a certain row to get a preview of the executed query.

[image: Mouseover a row in history image]

Another option is to go to Query details and user the three dots and View Query Profile to get to the Activity/Query page

[image: Query details image]

And from there go to Query history where you can view the SQL code

[image: Query history choose tab image]

Comment: I agree that is how to get to a single page profile, I was wanting the comparative many N last queries, and how they compare from one place. When performance turning something it is the comparisons that is what is wanted

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim That is correct. Using the Activity / Query history would be the best option now I guess so the same as in the answer by Phil, but they have changed the name from Compute to Activity in the menu. But the old way was easier.